# Como aplicar chmod 777 com php em pasta principal e varias subpastas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso aplicar com um único código em php chmod 777 em uma pasta e subpastas de uma só vez no caso eu tenho uma pasta chamada imagens e dentro dela tem 4 subpastas preciso realizar o chmod 777 nelas com um único código ao invés de usar o código abaixo.

E existe alguma maneira deu aplicar no caso o chmod 777 na pasta imagens e em todas as suas subpastas com um único código ?

```
<?php
$chmod = chmod("imagens", 0777);
$chmod = chmod("imagens/medias", 0777);
$chmod = chmod("imagens/capas", 0777);
$chmod = chmod("imagens/icones", 0777);
$chmod = chmod("imagens/screen_shots", 0777);

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando recursão. Existe uma classe chamada [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) que resolve o seu problema. Veja o exemplo retirado do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

```
<?php

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathname));

    foreach($iterator as $item) {
         chmod($item, $filemode);
    }

?>
```

No seu caso, `$filemode = 0777` e `$pathname = 'imagens'`

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, não esqueça de validá-la =)

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira faltou explicar a função do `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

Comment: @gmsantos http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: @gmsantos acho que não era bem esse o escopo da pergunta, por isso que apenas linkei a documentação

Comment: @caio sugeri isso para deixar a resposta mais rica :)  alem de resolver a dúvida gosto de explicar o pq usei método x.